# How to load data into tensorflow model fit lazily?

Tags: pandas, image, tensorflow

I have a pandas dataframe which has columns (filename, x1, y1, x2, y2, class). filename is the name of an image file and (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) describe a bounding box in that image. For now I have created a script which cropped all the bounding boxes and saved it in another directory.
What I want to do is somehow have tensorflow read from dataframe and load, crop and process only the row it is currently on. The dataframe is a very big so cropping and storing image in dataframe doesn't seem like a good option.
Is there a way to achive (filename, x1, y1, x2, y2, lazy_crop() ) such that lazy_crop() is called only when tensorflow needs data from that row.

Comment: Yes. ``ImageDataGenerator`` is a generator which does not load all data once into memory. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator

Comment: I want to crop each file acc to the dataframe, but the flow_from_dataframe doesn't accept an additional function for that and even if it loads the dataframe lazily there is no meaning if the dataframe already contains the image.

Comment: It accepts an additional function. Check ``preprocessing_function`` argument.

Comment: the preprocessing_function only takes the image as input so i won't have the corresponding bounding box co ordinates from dataframe.